# Access token for Facebook Graph API

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been looking for an exact explanation of how to get and use access tokens for public pages.

I'm trying to list the events for a public page, then grab all the event IDs and make another call to each ID, then send the complete list somewhere (I will handle that, I just need access to the JSON information for each event, which I can't). The following works for me:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/pages/PAGEID/events?accesstoken=ACCESSTOKEN
```

And gives me a list of all the events - when, title, where etc. But if I try to do:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/events/EVENTID/?accesstoken=ACCESSTOKEN
```

I get an error 100 - why is this? Shouldn't this work? All the events are public, and since fetching the page's events works, it shouldn't be because of a restriction (alcohol, location etc) I assume?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ID should be used directly after the facebook URL, like:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/EVENTID?access_token=ACCESSTOKEN
```